# Display %ROWCOUNT value in a select statement

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems-cache-studio

How is the result of `%ROWCOUNT` displayed in the SQL statement.

Example

```
Select top 10 * from myTable.
```

I would like the results to have a `rowCount` for each row returned in the result set

Ex

```
+----------+--------+---------+
|rowNumber |Column1 |Column2  |
+----------+--------+---------+
|1         |A       |B        |
|2         |C       |D        |
+----------+--------+---------+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no any simple way to do it. You can add Sql Procedure with this functionality and use it in your SQL statements.
For example, class:

```
Class Sample.Utils Extends %RegisteredObject
{

ClassMethod RowNumber(Args...) As %Integer [ SqlProc, SqlName = "ROW_NUMBER" ]
{
  quit $increment(%rownumber)
}

}
```

and then, you can use it in this way:

```
SELECT TOP 10 Sample.ROW_NUMBER(id) rowNumber, id,name,dob 
FROM sample.person 
ORDER BY ID desc
```

You will get something like below

```
+-----------+-------+-------------------+-----------+
|rowNumber  |ID     |Name               |DOB        |
+-----------+-------+-------------------+-----------+
|1          |200    |Quigley,Neil I.    |12/25/1999 |
|2          |199    |Zevon,Imelda U.    |04/22/1955 |
|3          |198    |O'Brien,Frances I. |12/03/1944 |
|4          |197    |Avery,Bart K.      |08/20/1933 |
|5          |196    |Ingleman,Angelo F. |04/14/1958 |
|6          |195    |Quilty,Frances O.  |09/12/2012 |
|7          |194    |Avery,Susan N.     |05/09/1935 |
|8          |193    |Hanson,Violet L.   |05/01/1973 |
|9          |192    |Zemaitis,Andrew H. |03/07/1924 |
|10         |191    |Presley,Liza N.    |12/27/1978 |
+-----------+-------+-------------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to rewrite your query then you can use a view counter to do what you are looking for.  Here is a link to the [docs](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_from#RSQL_C64362).

The short version is you move your query into a FROM clause sub query and use the special field %vid.

```
SELECT v.%vid AS Row_Counter, Name 
  FROM (SELECT TOP 10 Name FROM Sample.Person ORDER BY Name) v 

Row_Counter Name
1           Adam,Thelma P.
2           Adam,Usha J.
3           Adams,Milhouse A.
4           Allen,Xavier O.
5           Avery,James R.
6           Avery,Kyra G.
7           Bach,Ted J.
8           Bachman,Brian R.
9           Basile,Angelo T.
10          Basile,Chad L.
```